# Meson: how to copy subproject file to build directory?

Tags: cmake, makefile, gnu-make, meson-build

I'm using [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) build system to build a simple executable `app`.

Problem is: the executable needs to have access to file `file.txt` which is located in the separate `utils` repository. The executable `app` reads this file at runtime and can't work without accessing it.

I have pulled in the `utils` repository as a [Meson subproject](https://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html), but I am not sure how would I copy the `subprojects/utils/file.txt` to a `builddir`[directory where the executable is built](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_builtin_meson.html#mesoncurrent_build_dir). Currently the `app` is built without problems, but when I run it, it fails to find `file.txt`.

How do I copy the `subprojects/utils/file.txt` to `builddir`?

Comment: https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/860 some comments might help

Comment: @AbdullahAlattar Thanks, but I don't see anything related to tagging subprojects in that discussion.

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment on your issue: current versions of Meson isolate subprojects in sandboxes, and make it very difficult to move things in or out of those subprojects. This does not however mean you could not define a custom target that copies the files - but you will need to reliably need to know where those files are, and this is also something that is not currently trivial in meson. You may want to consider vendorizing your utils project as a git submodule in a directory outside of subprojects and simply include the meson.build in that from your main mason.build.

Answer (score -1):

https://mesonbuild.com/Fs-module.html#copyfile

```
copy = fs.copyfile('input-file', 'output-file')
```

Comment: This is incorrect specifically because the question is about moving files form subprojects. Meson sandboxes subprojects, so trying to copy a file from a subproject raises a sandbox violation and the copy will fail.